# Implications of Not Zero-Centering Data in Diffusion Models: Impact on Performance and Stability?

Tags: math, generative-model, diffusion-models

I've been exploring the implementation and theory behind diffusion models, particularly in how they manage the latent space. A recurring theme is the emphasis on zero-centering the latent space and ensuring a standard variance.

My question revolves around the fundamental aspects of the diffusion process, specifically:

**What are the theoretical and practical implications of not zero-centering the data and not maintaining a standard variance in the latent space of a diffusion model?**
Given the definition of the diffusion process, which iteratively refines noise into structured data, I'm curious if the model inherently requires zero-centered data to function optimally. Does the mathematical formulation of the diffusion process hint at potential issues or inefficiencies if the data is not zero-centered and does not have a standard variance?